# Error: Browser auto increments number in json response

Tags: json, browser, numbers, response, increment

I have an API, that returns a JSON object. One of the keys of the JSON object has the value of type 'array of integers'. The issue is browser increments the numbers in the array by 1 when receiving it from API.

Here is the API response received from browser and postman: THe one received from the postman is the actual data. Why browser behaves erroneously?

**Browser**:

[image]

**Postman**:

[image]